# Hangfire.Redis.StackExchange does not seem to fetch jobs with Redis cluster

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, hangfire

I have been using [Hangfire.redis.StackExchange](https://github.com/marcoCasamento/Hangfire.Redis.StackExchange) for a while now with Redis cluster under kubernetes.
As the library was not handling transactions across cluster, I simply used a curly braced prefix to have all my hangfire related keys being stored on a single node. The prefix is of the form `MyCompany.MyProject.HangFire:{Dev}:`

Today I stumbled on [this commit](https://github.com/marcoCasamento/Hangfire.Redis.StackExchange/commit/856f63835677c20f2c544b18725a74722fd1ec81) which seemed to solve my initial issue.
I upgraded to version 1.7.2 of Hangfire.redis.StackExchange which contains this commit.

I set `UseTransactions` to `false` and removed the curly braces from my prefix.
Considering jobs enqueueing, everything went well. Keys were dispatched across all my redis cluster nodes, which was the desired behaviour.
**But the JobServer never fetches any of these enqueued jobs**. Nothing seems to happen.
**UPDATE** after activating logging (always a good idea), I see that errors are in fact being raised on the jobserver side "*Multi-key operations must involve a single slot; keys can use hash tags to help this, ...*"

I subscribed to the redis channels with the `psubscribe` option and can see the notification being triggered.
If I just change the prefix and put back curly braces, the keys are then stored on a single node and the jobs are fetched correctly.

Has someone already encountered this issue ? Did I miss something obvious ?

Redis is version 4.0.11
Hangfire.Redis.StackExchange, StackEchange.Redis and Hangfire.Core are ugraded to the latest version.